# Can't delete cookie, but can read

Tags: php, cookies, setcookie, isset

**1.** `setcookie('Username', 12, time()-3600);`

**2.** `if(isset($_COOKIE['Username']) doSomething();`

*1.* doesn't work, but *2.* works, this makes no sense to me, how can it read the cookie but not be able to delete it?

This is how I've set the cookie: `setcookie('Username', $user['username'], time()+3600*24);`

I should have probably defined the path, but still, why does one thing work and the other doesn't? I need to find a way to delete that cookie because I've changed my website folder and there's 1000's of users with active cookies on their browsers, and not being able to delete them is generating an infinite redirection loop.

**EDIT**
I was able to delete the cookie by changing the path to /: `setcookie('Username', 12, time()-3600, '/');`
It still doesn't explain why I was able to access the cookie on a different path...

**EDIT**
For some reason, that above worked that time, but now it doesn't working anymore... Starting to make me insane.

**EDIT**
I forgot to change the new cookies path... That's why it wasn't working again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to empty that value. `setcookie('Username', "", time()-3600);`

Comment: Doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: It should. See the referneces [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) and [here #2](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)